# How low can I set the TTL of a DNS record and expect it to be honoured?

Tags: dns

I wish to set the TTL of my DNS record to something pretty low, like say 5 minutes (or 300 seconds) I wish to do this so that in 24 hours when this change has propagated, I will be able to issue further changes and have them respected within the 5 minute window.

The overall reason for this is because I am about to move a website from one box to another (different IP). Upon completing this move, I hope to shut down the origin al box and for everything to be work perfectly.

However I am a realist and want to prepare for the eventuality that something will go wrong. In a case such as this I would like to be able to switch back to the original site and to have that switch occur within a very small window (ie the 5 minutes)

If all should go well then I hope to change the TTL value back to ~24hours.

So to requote the question: "**How low can I set the TTL of a DNS record and expect it to be honoured?**"

Comment: I think this is going to be highly implementation-specific, and any answers will be opinions unless representatives of ISPs and other companies that run major DNS servers actually come forward with exact answers.

Answer (score 5):

Standards (RFC1035) permit any TTL, from 0 seconds and up, and as it's a standard, every application under the sun *required* to honor it.

Real world is different, and maybe some *bad* ISPs ignore low TTL values and enforce some minimal TTL on all records that pass via their servers. I don't see real practical reason to do so.

Some browsers cache DNS for some small time (pecifically chrome caches DNS for 60 seconds, I think it's regardless of TTL but not sure).

I'd expect more than 95% of your traffic to honor your low TTL. I'm not a big expert in the field.

Comment: Someone with high-traffic website could change a DNS record and wait, how fast the traffic moves to the new location.